# YARN job fails due to the connection issue

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, yarn-workspaces, hadoop3

I've `hadoop-3.3.6` setup in the Kubernetes cluster, all the hadoop components are exposed via ClusterIP services, I'm able to telnet to the ports that are exposed from respective pods. But when I run the  example job from datanode pod (tried even from the resourcemanager pod), I get the following error

`hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.6.jar wordcount /README.txt /MROutput`

```
2023-12-08 21:18:57,722 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil: Updating Configuration
2023-12-08 21:18:58,323 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2023-12-08 21:18:58,544 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2023-12-08 21:18:58,544 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2023-12-08 21:18:58,714 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens: [Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1702069922844_0002, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@71c3b41)]
2023-12-08 21:18:58,827 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2023-12-08 21:18:59,992 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nodemanager.hadoop.svc.cluster.local.hadoop/10.233.51.169:37127. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-12-08 21:19:00,994 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nodemanager.hadoop.svc.cluster.local.hadoop/10.233.51.169:37127. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-12-08 21:19:01,996 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nodemanager.hadoop.svc.cluster.local.hadoop/10.233.51.169:37127. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2023-12-08 21:19:02,003 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.net.ConnectException: Call From nodemanager-8fc5cdf9d-q9kwx/10.233.74.107 to nodemanager.hadoop.svc.cluster.local.hadoop:37127 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:930)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:251)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:140)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1457)
    ... 4 more

2023-12-08 21:19:02,004 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping MapTask metrics system...
2023-12-08 21:19:02,005 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system stopped.
2023-12-08 21:19:02,006 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system shutdown complete.
```

The `nodemanager.hadoop.svc.cluster.local.hadoop` is my service hostname which is correct but the PORT `37127` is not opened in that service and its random as I run the job every time, so I cannot expose that port out of my service

I'm running above job from my `datanode` which is able to connect to `nodemanager.hadoop.svc.cluster.local.hadoop` service but via diff. IPs that are exposed. I could connect from `nodemanager-8fc5cdf9d-q9kwx/10.233.74.107` pod to the service via diff. IPs that are exposed via that service.

Also when I tried to check the port creation using `netstat` inside the `nodemanager` while running the job, `tcp6` PORT `37127` does exist as long as the job was run.

Looks like I'm missing some config. settings? Could someone please help me?  (struggling for a couple of days on this)

The Job finishes with failure.
[Job status after completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvptU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the port range using `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.job.client.port-range`, then expose them via kubernetes service, it works now.